# Insert dataset to a table PostgreSQL

Tags: c#, sql, wcf, postgresql

I am converting a WCF service with a SQL Server backend to PostgreSQL. I am using [`Npgsql`](http://npgsql.projects.pgfoundry.org/) but it does not have a bulk copy option. **test** is the dataset here.

This is my sql code,

```
        DataSet ds = DuobaseHandler.ToDataSet(test);
        DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];
        string TableNameOrig = "CDA." + TableName;
        DataTable dataTable = dt; 
        try
        {
            ConnectionStringSettings mConString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CommonDataConnection"];
            string[] columnNames = dt.Columns.Cast<System.Data.DataColumn>()
                     .Select(x => x.ColumnName)
                     .ToArray();
            string[] ColumnsFinal = columnNames.Take(columnNames.Count() - 2).ToArray();
            using (SqlConnection ConnectionSQL = new SqlConnection(mConString.ConnectionString))
            {
                ConnectionSQL.Open();
                // Delete old entries
                SqlCommand truncate = new SqlCommand("TRUNCATE TABLE" + " " + "CDA." + TableName, ConnectionSQL);
                truncate.ExecuteNonQuery();


            }
            SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(mConString.ConnectionString, SqlBulkCopyOptions.TableLock)
            {
                DestinationTableName = TableNameOrig,
                BatchSize = 100000,
                BulkCopyTimeout = 360
            };
            foreach (var item in ColumnsFinal)
            {
                bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(item.ToString(), item.ToString());
            }

            bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dataTable);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
        }
        return true;
```

Comment: The product is called **PostgreSQL** (see http://www.postgresql.org/) - and **NOT** "posegresql" as you keep insisting on misspelling it .... Please stop undoing my fixes to you post - I'm trying to make it more useful and readable here

Comment: @marc_s Yes, i wrongly rejected your edit, it came in the middle while reviewing others posts sorry for that. you can edit now

Comment: nPgSQL *does* have a bulk copy feature, it just doesn't have the same interface. See [`NpgsqlCopyIn`](http://npgsql.projects.pgfoundry.org/docs/api/Npgsql.NpgsqlCopyIn.html). It would be interesting to write a wrapper to support the MS SQL Server interfaces instead, but it doesn't look like anyone's done it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

nPgSQL *does* have a bulk copy feature, it just doesn't have the same interface. See [`NpgsqlCopyIn`](http://npgsql.projects.pgfoundry.org/docs/api/Npgsql.NpgsqlCopyIn.html).

It would be interesting to write a wrapper to support the MS SQL Server interfaces instead, but it doesn't look like anyone's done it, so you'll need to convert to the nPgSQL interface or write a compatibility wrapper.

[This blog](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/alexander_kuznetsov/archive/2013/11/04/learning-postgresql-bulk-loading-data.aspx) might be useful.

Comment: Ya i know that npsqlcopyin would work, but it needs a columns of type string, will try it anyways. Thanks